# Delete a vector without deleting the array

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

I'm trying to populate a vector of doubles in C++ and pass the associated array to Fortran. But I'm having trouble freeing the rest of the memory associated with the vector. I'd like to avoid copying. Here's what I have:

```
std::vector<double> *vec = new std::vector<double>();
(*vec).push_back(1.0);
(*vec).push_back(2.0);
*arr = (*vec).data();            //arr goes to Fortran
```

How do I delete `vec` while keeping `arr` intact? Is there a way to nullify the pointer to `arr` in `vec` so that I can then delete `vec`?

**Update**

I see that I didn't give enough information here. A couple things:

1. I'm actually calling a C++ function in Fortran using iso_c_binding
2. I don't know how large the `vec` needs to be. The vector class looks good for this situation

I might try Guillaume's suggestion eventually, but for now, I'm passing `vec` to the Fortran and calling another C++ function to delete it once I'm done with the data

Comment: This is not supported by `std::vector`.

Comment: In c++, the preferred way of access a pointer's member is the `->` operator. `vec->push_back(1.0);`.

Comment: Heap allocated STL containers are a good way of shooting yourself in the foot. They are not suited for polymorphism and they goes well with value semantics. Doing `new std::vector` is kind of a way to have all inconveniences of the STL, whilst having no advantages.

Comment: Why are you creating the vector with `new`? There is almost never any good reason for doing that.

Comment: I'm using `new` so that the data remains accessible in Fortran after going out of scope in C++

Comment: Right now there's a memory leak. That's what I'm trying to fix

Comment: Fortran will take ownership of `arr`, but not the rest of `vec`

Comment: As for default vector manage memory by itself you need to write your own allocator. Far easier is to just copy content of vector to an array.

Answer (score 3):

You need to rethink your program design.

Somehow, somewhere, you need to keep an array alive while Fortran is using it. So whatever context you're using to access Fortran should probably be responsible for ownership of this array.

```
class fortran_context {
    /*Blah blah blah whatever API you're using to access Fortran*/
    void * arr;
    std::vector<double> vec; //Don't allocate this as a pointer; makes no sense!
public:
    fortran_context() {
        arr = //Do whatever is necessary to setup Fortran stuff. I'm assuming your
        //api has some kind of "get_array_pointer" function that you'll use.
    }

    ~fortran_context() {
        //Do the cleanup for the fortran stuff
    }

    //If you want to spend time figuring out a robust copy constructor, you may.
    //Personally, I suspect it's better to just delete it, and make this object non-copyable.
    fortran_context(fortran_context const&) = delete;

    std::vector<double> & get_vector() {
        return vec;
    }

    std::vector<double> const& get_vector() const {
        return vec;
    }

    void assign_vector_to_array() {
        *arr = vec.data();
    }

    void do_stuff_with_fortran() {
        assign_vector_to_array();
        //???
    }
};

int main() {
    fortran_context context;
    auto & vec = context.get_vector();
    vec.push_back(1.0);
    vec.push_back(2.0);
    context.do_stuff_with_fortran();
    return 0;
} //Cleanup happens automatically due to correct implementation of ~fortran_context()
```

I've abstracted a lot of this because I don't know what API you're using to access Fortran, and I don't know what kind of work you're doing with this array. But this is, by far, the safest way to ensure that

- The vector's allocated memory exists so long as you are doing stuff in Fortran
- The memory associated with the vector will be cleaned up properly when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I delete vec while keeping arr intact? Is there a way to nullify the pointer to arr in vec so that I can then delete vec?

The library does not provide any built-in capability to do that. You have to do the bookkeeping work yourself.

1. Allocate memory for the data and copy data from the vector.
2. Send the data to FORTRAN.
3. Decide when it is safe to deallocate the data and then delete them.

---

```
// Fill up data in vec
std::vector<double> vec;
vec.push_back(1.0);
vec.push_back(2.0);

// Allocate memory for arr and copy the data from vec
double* arr = new double[vec.size()];
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), arr);

// use arr

// delete arr
delete [] arr;
```

Comment: It would be important to note though, that we are just moving the problem of lifetime management from the vector to the copy of the vector. Why not keep the vector from being destroyed while you are using its data in the first place?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz, That would be OK if `vec` is created in the same stack frame or scope where the call to FORTRAN is made.

Comment: @R Sahu, right, well more code is needed in his OP for it to make much sense. Just want to make sure the OP understand the concept of "don't destroy things while you are using them"

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible. std::vector, being a well behaved template class will release the internals that it owns and manages when it is destroyed.

You will have to keep vector alive while you are using its contents, which makes perfect sense. Otherwise, you will have to make a copy.

Also, I don't see why you are allocating the vector on the heap, it doesn't seem needed at all.

Comment: I'm using new so that the data remains accessible in Fortran after going out of scope in C++

Comment: new on the vector has no bearing on the data being available in Fortran. The vector allocates memory internally for its contents itself, as do all the STL containers.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz vector only by default manage memory by itself, but there is possibility to provide external memory management through non default allocator.

Comment: @Logman, sure, one can provide a custom allocator, but that is still a completely separate thing from newing the vector itself. Either way, the vector manages its internals either by allocating and releasing them itself of calling your allocator.

Answer (score -1):

> How do I delete vec while keeping arr intact? Is there a way to nullify the pointer to arr in vec so that I can then delete vec?

You don't.

---

I think you misuse or misunderstood what vector is for. It is not meant to expose memory management of the underlying array, but to represent a dynamically sized array as a regular type.

If you need to explicitly manage memory, I'd suggest you to use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`. Since unique pointers offers a way to manage memory and to release it's resource without deleting it, I think it's a good candidate to meet your needs.

```
auto arr = std::make_unique<double[]>(2);
arr[0] = 1.;
arr[1] = 2.;
auto data = arr.release();

// You have to manage `data` memory manually,
// since the unique pointer released it's resource.

// arr is null here
// data is a pointer to an array, must be deleted manually later.

delete[] data;
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like exactly what I need

Comment: To the downvoter: what is wrong with this answer? It's much similar to RSahu answer but with unique ptr instead of raw array.